# Finding the slimmest Spanning Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-tree

This is basically an ICPC Tokyo regional question - Slim Span(UVA -1395)

Link to the question-https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=4141

The question states that the slimmest tree is one with minimum difference between its shortest and longest edge and the tree itself does not need to be a minimum spanning tree, it just needs to be a spanning tree.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

const int MAX = 110;
struct ii{
    int first,second,third;
    ii(int x, int y, int z){
        first=x;//destination node
        second=y;//weight of the edge
        third=z;//slimness
    }
    bool operator<(const ii& rhs) const
    {
        return third > rhs.third;//slimmest edge first
    }
};

vector <ii> adj[MAX];//adjacency list

int prim(int source, int n){

    int maximum=-1, minimum=987654321;//maximum and minimum edge lengths
    set<int> notvisited;//nodes not yet visited by prim
    priority_queue< ii, vector< ii > > pq;

    for(int i=1;i<=n; ++i){
        notvisited.insert(i);
    }
    pq.push(ii(source, 0,0));
    set<int>::iterator iterator1;

    while(!pq.empty() && !notvisited.empty()){
        ii temp=pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        int s=temp.first;//target
        int w=temp.second;//weight of edge
          //if visited->continue
        if((iterator1=notvisited.find(s))==notvisited.end())continue;
        notvisited.erase(s);
        if(w!=0){
            maximum=max(maximum,w);
            minimum=min(minimum,w);
        }
        for(int i=0; i<adj[source].size(); ++i){
            int target=adj[source][i].first;
            int targetw=adj[source][i].second;
            int slimness=targetw-w;
            if((iterator1=notvisited.find(target))!=notvisited.end()){
                pq.push(ii(target,targetw,max(slimness, 0-slimness)));
            }
        }


    }
    return maximum-minimum;
}
```

My idea was to sort the edges using the slimness instead of the weights. It is not working because from the very start it always marks the shortest edge as visited.

How do I correct my program to solve this problem?

Sample Input-

4 6//number of nodes, number of edges

1 2 10//source destination weight

1 3 100

1 4 90

2 3 20

2 4 80

3 4 40

Output-
20

Comment: Seems like a [dynamic connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity#Fully_dynamic_connectivity) data structure could be used to quickly find a slimmest connected edge cover, from which it's simple to find a slimmest spanning tree.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.